# Why do we use $\frac{\pi}{180}$ to convert from degrees to radians?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

If I want to convert from degrees to radians, I can use the function that takes degree value as an input, multiplies it with $\frac{\pi}{180}$ and returns the radian value: $\operatorname{DtoR}(d)=d \times \frac{\pi}{180}$.

And if I want to go from radians to degrees I need to only go backwards and  divide radian value with $\frac{\pi}{180}$ (e.g. multiply it with $\frac{180}{\pi}$): $\operatorname{RtoD}(r)=r \times \frac{180}{\pi}$.

My question is this: Why does multiplying/dividing with $\frac{\pi}{180}$ converts degrees into radians/radians into degrees? Why exactly that number, not some other? Also, does this work only for unit circle, or for any circle?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The circumference of the unit circle is $2\pi$ which corresponds to 360°.

Comment: Either no one commented on this post, or he simply reposted it because he wasn't satisfied from the answers he initially received.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, for unit circle (unit circle's radius is 1). If radius of a circle is not 1, the circumference is not $2\pi$.

Comment: Because $180^\circ = \pi \text{ radians}. \qquad$

Comment: Go here $\longrightarrow$ https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/trig-functions/intro-to-radians-alg2/v/we-converting-degrees-to-radians

Comment: @P.E.K.K.A. That was a different question.

Comment: Oh then please disregard my previous comment.

Comment: @Vuk: The radian measure of an angle subtended is the length of the corresponding path on a unit circle. Of course the length depends on the radius. I still don't understand what you are asking. If two quantities have some fixed relationship how could it be a different number?

Comment: @copper.hat I understood it in the meantime. That's why I removed the question that was directed at you.

Comment: Your main problem is you don't understand radians. Work on that first.

Comment: Why do we use 12 to convert from feet to inches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at these ratios:
$\frac{180}{d}=\frac{\pi}{r}$

Where $d$ is the degrees and $r$ is radians.
Knowing that $\pi$ radians is 180 degrees one can setup this ratio to find the values they're looking for.

Finding degrees: $d=\frac{180}{\pi}r$
Finding radians: $r=\frac{\pi}{180}d$

These equations are simply derived from the first ratio.

It doesn't only need to be $\frac{\pi}{180}$, it can also be setup as:
$\frac{360}{d}=\frac{2\pi}{r}$
Because it is also known that $2\pi$ radians is a full revolution about the circle just as 360 degrees is.

Comment: What if $2\pi \neq 360^\circ$? Check out my comment on the gt6989b's answer.

Comment: This never occurs? Unless the unit definitions were changed (ie. a full revolution equals 378deg), this never happens. $\pi$ is a constant, it doesn't matter how the circle is changed. As long as the circle is a circle, $\pi$ still holds true.

Comment: Also note that $2\pi=360^\circ$ **numerically** is not true. It's the ratios that matter.

Comment: Ok. So $2\pi=360^\circ$ is always true. I guess I can't understand why because I don't know how a radian is defined, but I'll look it up. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, I don't understand that result you have written to find $d$, I have obtained another result:
$$\begin{array}{lcl} \frac{180}{d} & = & \frac{\pi}{r} \\ \frac{d}{180} & = & \frac{r}{\pi} \\ \frac{d}{180} \cdot 180 & = & \frac{r}{\pi} \cdot 180 \\ d & = & \frac{180}{\pi}\cdot r \end{array}$$ Why I obtain this different result? thanks.

Comment: @JB-Franco your result is correct. Thank you for noticing this mistake :)

Answer (score 5):

A full circle is $360^\circ$ and also $2\pi$ radians. Thus $360^\circ = 2\pi\text{ rad}$. We simplify by dividing by two.

Comment: another case where [τ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(geometry)#Tau_proposals) would be more natural than π

Answer (score 5):

Think of it as solving proportions. We have $$\pi \text{ radians} = 180^\circ$$ and you want to convert $$r \text{ radians} = d^\circ.$$ Hence you get
$$
\frac{\pi}{r} = \frac{180}{d}
$$
which simplifies to
$$
r = \frac{\pi}{180} d \quad \text{or equivalently} \quad d = \frac{180}{\pi} r.
$$

Comment: What if radius isn't 1? For example, if $r=2$, do I use $\frac{\pi}{90}$? I think yes, but just to confirm.

Comment: @Vuk nothing here depends on radius. Radians are a measure of *angle* not length

Comment: But the formula of circle's circumference is $r2\pi$. If $r=2$, then the circle's circumference ($360^\circ$) is $4\pi$. Then $90^\circ=\pi,180^\circ=2\pi$ and so on. I can't apply $\frac{\pi}{180}$, because $180^\circ \neq \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

The **radian** is defined as the plane angle subtended by any circular arc divided by its radius.

When the circular arc is actually congruent to the circle, the length is $2\pi r=2\pi=$ [$\tau$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(geometry)#Tau_proposals) (for **a unit circle**). The angle subtended by this arc is $360^\text{o}$, and therefore $1\:\text{radian}=\frac{360}{\tau}=\frac{180}{\pi}$.

So: $$r\text{ radians}=\text{d}\cdot \frac{180}{\pi}\\ d\text{ degrees} = \frac{r}{\frac{180}{\pi}}=\frac{180r}{\pi}$$

Answer (score -1):

Since circumference =2pie*r if we take half circle it would be pie*r in which rotation of angle is 180 degree and  arc length would be pie*r then we get theta =pie =180 degree